# How restart loop when server returns the code 429

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a small code to receive data through API.
Api requests have a 1 minute timeout. If the requests come more often, then the server returns the code 429.
Question: how do I get the server response code and restart the loop after a minute? Tried "try ... catch" with timeout, but it doesn't work as it should. I'm new to programming, so I don't know how to do it correctly.

My code:

```js
function WBstocks() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('WBstocks');
  sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).clear();
  const apikey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  var parseDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
  Logger.log(parseDate);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  for (let n=0; n<5; n++){
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://suppliers-stats.wildberries.ru/api/v1/supplier/stocks?dateFrom=2021-02-03'+'&key='+ apikey);
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    Logger.log('https://suppliers-stats.wildberries.ru/api/v1/supplier/stocks?dateFrom='+ date +'&key='+ apikey);
    var arr = [];
    for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      arr[i] = [];
      arr[i][0] = data[i].lastChangeDate;
      arr[i][1] = data[i].supplierArticle;
      arr[i][2] = data[i].techSize;
      arr[i][3] = data[i].barcode;
      arr[i][4] = data[i].quantity;
      arr[i][5] = data[i].isSupply;
      arr[i][6] = data[i].isRealization;
      arr[i][7] = data[i].quantityFull;
      arr[i][8] = data[i].quantityNotInOrders;
      arr[i][9] = data[i].warehouseName;
      arr[i][10] = data[i].inWayToClient;
      arr[i][11] = data[i].inWayFromClient;
      arr[i][12] = data[i].nmId;
      arr[i][13] = data[i].subject;
      arr[i][14] = data[i].category;
      arr[i][15] = data[i].daysOnSite;
      arr[i][16] = data[i].brand;
      arr[i][17] = data[i].SCCode;
      arr[i][18] = data[i].Price;
      arr[i][19] = data[i].Discount;
      arr[i][20] = parseDate;
    }
    if(arr.length === 0){break;}
    Utilities.sleep(6200)
    }
  Logger.log(arr.length);
  Logger.log(arr[0].length);
  var ct = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(ct+1,1,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### HTTP Status code 429 means you have run out of requests to make

Some resource has been exhausted, perhaps a per-user quota, or perhaps the entire file system is out of space. Sheets API has its [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) that allows 100 requests per 100 seconds (1 second per request) per user unless you have a billing project you can't change this quota.

Receiving a status 429 is not an error, the server is asking you to stop making requests.

Regarding your code [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) function takes miliseconds as argument so you are waiting 6.2 seconds so keep in mind that each item in array data.